# Out of Office was setup on an email which is now an alias; anyway to remove that out of office?

Tags: email, exchange

We have a user who a few months ago went through a process of condensing the multiple email addresses they had (All of which had their own associated mailboxes) into one email address. The past email addresses were setup as alias's. However it seems like one of these previous mailboxes had an out of office configured on it and wasn't disabled before the 'merge'

Is there a way to be able to disable that out of office given that the associated mailbox no longer exists and that email is just an alias? My understanding of Exchange is that if the mailbox is no longer there no configuration can be done on it at all

Comment: I'm unsure with exchange but maybe [this Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-mailboxautoreplyconfiguration?view=exchange-PS) link might help

Answer (score 2):

I tried testing in my Exchange server lab using steps below and the result indicate there's no need to worry about the OOF configured for the OOF set previously for the alias mailbox.

1. Enable OOF for user10@contoso.com
2. Disabling the mailbox of user10@contoso.com
3. Add user10@contoso.com as an alias address for user2@contoso.com.
4. Send an email to address "user10@contoso.com", no automatic reply is received.

As I understand it, the test result makes sense because the OOF configuration is stored in the mailbox, now that the mailbox has already been disabled, it will not be triggered any longer.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Probably worth noting that out of office replies are special server side rules. They may have migrated the rules during the mailbox consolidation. Message tracing would easily show it.